# Going to Today in Outlook Web Calendar with a shortcut key

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

How can I jump to "Today" while in calendar view using a keyboard shortcut key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/microsoft-365-keyboard-shortcuts-for-outlook-on-the-web/

It's Shift+Alt+Y - not ideal to have a 2 handed short-cut for this regular action, but it works.

Comment: I have not been able to find it in any documentation - it's not shown in the list of shortcuts for Outlook for Web (nor for the desktop version btw).

Answer (score 1):

Press the Home button on your keyboard

Comment: This answer is for Windows 10 calendar, not OWA calendar.

Comment: This sometimes works in OWA, other times it makes the "cursor" on the month calendar at the top left go the the first position instead of moving to home.